# Share hyperlink via Android Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, hyperlink

This is my hyperlink

```
String linkText = "Visit the <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a> web page."
```

I have add this in below function

```
fun whatsappshr(context: Context, displayData: Display_data) {
            val message : String = displayData.appdata + linkText
            val Intentfun = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            Intentfun.type = "text/plain"
            Intentfun.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
            Intentfun.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  message)
            try {
                ContextCompat.startActivity(itemView.context, Intentfun, null)
            } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Whatsapp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

when my app share the data via Intent, it does not send a link. It send the whole data from linkText.
Is there any way to send hyperlink via android intent? Guys, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I think this is not related to how does Android share strings. I think it's the share destination (Whatsapp here) responsibility to parse the string into HTML, Android will just pass the string as it is to your share app.